# Set a theme on a View programmatically on Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop

Android 5.0 Lollipop added the ability to set a theme for different views (not just the Activity).

```
android:theme="@style/MyAwesomeTheme"
```

Is there a way to set the theme on a view dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android:theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#Inheritance) changes specific attributes specified in the theme resource. You could instantiate specific view using any overloaded constructor, like `View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)`. which basically is what inflater does.

For example `v7.widget.Toolbar` tries to create themed context out of resource `android:theme`right in the super call of the constructor, which is more or less what I mentioned above. Only certain widgets override application theme using `android:theme`.

I'm not sure if is possible to directly specify theme, rather than instantiation mentioned above, or using supported individual attribute and its related method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it is impossible to change the theme dynamically after the view has been inflated/created.